# ./build command not found

Tags: ssh, compiling

trying to install dssh - https://github.com/PWZER/dssh

but the ./build.sh command is not found nor is any build command.

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in their installation steps they are missing a very vital step.  You need to clone the repo to your system.

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/PWZER/dssh
cd dssh
```

Now you should be able to run `./build.sh`